# datomic query - function that filters and binds

Tags: regex, clojure, datomic

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
(defn match? [m] (re-find (re-pattern "so (\\d+)") m))

(datomic.api/q 
  '[:find ?m
    :where [[?e :user/regex-match ?r]
            [(user/match? ?e) ?m]] 
   dbconn)
```

This gives me what I expect, but it calls "match?" twice per entity:

```
(datomic.api/q 
  '[:find ?m
    :where [[?e :user/regex-match ?r]
            [(user/match? ?e) ?m]
            [(user/match? ?e)] 
   dbconn)
```

Comment: adding a (identity ?m) instead of calling user/match? again seems like the best solution I've found so far. I wonder if its idiomatic in datomic queries, though?

Comment: What do you mean "calls `match?` twice per entity?" How can you tell? Could you provide some example data (i.e. Clojure collections)?

Comment: Also, Clojure regex expressions do not require you to escape the backslash. I had to change it to `#"so (\d+)"`

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about performance, use:

```
(->> (d/datoms (d/db conn) :aevt :user/regex-match)
 (filter #(user/match? (:v %)))
 (map :v))
```

which uses the [datomic.api/datoms](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/datoms) API to stream out `:user/regex-match` attribute values that match a predicate i.e. `user/match?`. This **guarantees** your predicate function is only executed once (per entity). Note you can replace `(map :v)` with `(map :e)` to retrieve their entity ids instead.

If you are ***really*** worried about performance and are willing to use additional memory to achieve it, use:

```
(def fast-match? (memoize match?))

(->> (d/datoms (d/db conn) :aevt :user/regex-match)
 (filter #(fast-match? (:v %)))
 (map :v))
```

Which creates a [memoized](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/memoize) version of your function. This version has even stronger performance guarantees since your predicate function will run **at most once** (i.e. once per each distinct value) and it could give you exceptional performance if your attribute values were part of a finite set.

For a full code sample, see https://gist.github.com/a2ndrade/5651065

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that `?m` gives you the matches, not the entity. You want something like the following:

```
user=> (->> (d/q '[:find ?e ?m :in $ :where [?e :user/regex-match ?r]
                                            [(user/match? ?r) ?m]]
            [[1 :user/regex-match "so 111"]
             [2 :user/regex-match "so 222"]
             [3 :user/regex-match "blah 333"]])
          (filter #(seq (second %))))

([2 ["so 222" "222"]] [1 ["so 111" "111"]])
```

Note that I mocked up the database using clojure collections.

Based on this output, you regex has a subexpression - which is why you probably see it "twice per entity."

I wonder if you might benefit from [the Datomic `filter` functionality](http://support.datomic.com/customer/portal/articles/897282-filtering-databases)?